# AES-Paillier Homomorphic encryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

How can I implement following problem in java code for addition? (here I use Paillier homomrphic encryption):
**Input would be to generate a new AES key, encrypt the private data with that key, encrypt the AES key with the FHE key, and send the FHE-encrypted AES key along with the AES encrypted data to the compute node.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a programming problem not a crypto problem. Beides, it is unclear as the question mentions Paillier and then talks about an FHE key.

Comment: You cannot implement AES homomorphically using Paillier. I suggest instead of starting with a solution to a particular problem and asking questions about it, describe your problem and ask for valid solutions, with strengths and weaknesses.